# How to store a sqlQuery data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rodbc

I iterate an array of dates which I use to create a sql query.

> dates <- c("2010-06-29", "2010-07-09", "2010-07-22")

```
fn1 <- function (N) 
{
    queryStart <- "SELECT something FROM somethingelse WHERE table.date ='"
    queryEnd <- "'AND table.something = 'foo'"
    for(i in 1:length(N)) {
        query1 <- paste(queryStart,N[i],queryEnd)
        result <- sqlQuery(con, query1)  //print(sqlQuery(con,query1) works as intended
    }
    return (result)
}
```

> fn1(dates)

How to fit all in one data frame? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I've not tested it though ...

```
fn1 <- function (N) 
{
    queryStart <- "SELECT something FROM somethingelse WHERE table.date ='"
    queryEnd <- "'AND table.something = 'foo'"
    allQueries<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=0));
    for(i in 1:length(N)) {
        query1 <- paste(queryStart,N[i],queryEnd)
        result <- sqlQuery(con, query1)  //print(sqlQuery(con,query1) works as intended
        if (nrow(allQueries) == 0){
            allQueries<-result;
        } 
        else{
            allQueries<-rbind(allQueries,result);
        }
    }
    return (allQueries);
}
```